# Two-file processing in awk

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

I have file :

result.txt

```
Apple fruits 10 20 30
Car  vehicle 40 50 60
Book study  70 80 90
```

Assume here `2nd column is a feature, 3rd column is Min, 4th column is Median, 5th column is Max`. I have another file config.txt which contains a property for each feature i.e.

config.txt

```
fruits Max
vehicle Median
study Min
```

So I want to write a script which shows only that column number for the feature which is defined in `config.txt` file.

Expected output:

```
Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70
```

I am following this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206489/10220825. Here what I have tried:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$2];next} $1 in arr {var =$2;print var}' result.txt config.txt
```

I can able to hold the property(like Min, Max, Median) in a variable for the corresponding feature defined in result.txt, but not able to display the column for that variable. Please suggest me an approach on how to print the column for the corresponding column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the feature names in the `config.txt` file to field indices in the `result.txt` file, e.g.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {ind["Min"]=3; ind["Median"]=4; ind["Max"]=5} 
  NR==FNR {arr[$1] = ind[$2]; next} 
  $2 in arr {print $1,$2,$(arr[$2])}
' config.txt result.txt
Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70
```